# Telegram iOS sample code showing error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, telegram, telegram-bot

I am developing chatting application using Telegram API,

When i download telegram code from [Telegram-iOS](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram)
it is showing me error `SSignalKit/SSignalKit.h` and `MTProtoKit/MTContext.h` file not found. I found the same file over internet and added it,

But now it is showing `#import "../../config.h"` file not found

From where can i get this file or how do i add it Telegram sample code?

**Please help and thanx in adavnce!!**

Comment: file and issue over here:https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/issues/new

Comment: @Krunal have you got the error free copy of Telegram iOS from git. ready to play Project?

Comment: @QadirHussain no, still facing issue

Answer (score 1):

This project is really hard to fix. Here is a [pull request](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/pull/17), which fix many compilation issues. But I still can not build after apply this pull request.

Is it OK to use Telegram 2.8? I download source code from https://telegram.org/apps. It is easier to build. Its version is 2.8; app's current version is 3.4; version of project in Github is 3.2.1. I have fixed some build issues and upload it to https://github.com/JohnWong/Telegraph.

Comment: When i download your proj from https://github.com/JohnWong/Telegraph. it shows me this error #include <openssl/obj_mac.h> file not found

Answer (score 1):

Do you have git installed?
Try run

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:peter-iakovlev/Telegram.git
```

Then Go inside the cloned project and open and run. Just try this as a fresh project. Leave aside the manually downloaded one.

It Also depends on this project. Clone it and drag it to Telegram project.

```
https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/MtProtoKit
```

Comment: When i run git clone line given by you in terminal it shows me **Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

Comment: @MadNik have you got the error free copy of Telegram iOS from git. ready to play Project?